# NODE_ENV is undefined even set Up was done properly

Tags: node.js

I have a **`util/config.json`** file like below:

```
{
"dev": {
    "db": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "user": "root",
        "pass":"*****"

      },

    "json_indentation": 4,
    "database": "my-app-db-dev"
}
"prod":{
    "db": {
        "host": "somethingt",
        "user": "root",
        "pass":"****"

      },

    "json_indentation": 4,
    "database": "my-app-db-dev"
}
```

}

from a **`util/config.js`** file, I have exported it to my `app.js`

```
const config = require('./config.json')
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'

const defaultConfig = config.environment;
console.log(defaultConfig)  // shows undefined why?
module.exports = defaultConfig
```

**`app.js`** is like so:

```
const express = require('express')
const config = require('./util/config')
```

but it my defaultConfig shows undefined and can't fetch the data for **`dev`** (**npm run dev in app.js directory**) while  I have set the NODE_ENV variable like this in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev && nodemon app.js",
        "prod": "set NODE_ENV=prod && nodemon app.js"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const defaultConfig = config.environment;` searches an `'environment'` string key in the `config`.

Try `const defaultConfig = config[environment];` to search for the value of the `environment` variable.

See [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) on MDN.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following snippet

```
const config = require('./config.json')
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'

const defaultConfig = config[environment];
console.log(defaultConfig)  // shows undefined why?
module.exports = defaultConfig
```

Comment: Hi when I run nodemon app it's working absolutely fine, but if I run npm run dev then it's not working. can you please tell me if my package.josn is right or not?? @ashish